# find hex value in list using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, networking

Input:
      we have given list

```
lst = ['a', '4', 'add', 'e', 'a', 'c0a8d202', '128', '4', '0', '32']
```

using regular expression find the hexvalue in given list
output:
      index of hexvalue(In our case hexvalue is `c0a8d202` then return the index 5)

Comment: what's wrong with `lst.index('c0a8d202')` ? what's the point of regular expressions here when you have the value already?

Comment: why not [0-9AFaf]{8} ?

Comment: maybe add 0x.... to your hex value 0xc0a8d202 then the things goes easy, search for preffix '0x'

Comment: you don't want to escape the curly braces.

Comment: Any element in the list qualifies as a hex value :)

Comment: homework probably.

Comment: @CristiFati Presumably he is looking for hex values which are of length 8.

Comment: @BcK: I know, just picking on technicalities....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import re

lst = ['a', '4', 'add', 'e', 'a', 'c0a8d202', '128', '4', '0', '32']
pattern = re.compile(r'c[0-9a-fA-F]?')

for i in lst:
    if re.search(pattern, i):
        print(lst.index(i))
```

**Note:** 
this is as per your desired output but i am agree with  @Jean-François Fabre who said that what's wrong with lst.index('c0a8d202') ? what's the point of regular expressions here when you have the value already?

Comment: Thank you !!     this is only example of lst, lst may be ["c0a8d202", "128", "4", "0", "32"] lst means any list.

Comment: Welcome, and i will also suggest you that if your hex values also can be anything then try to add '0x' in the start then modify the regular expression it will help you..